# Issues relating publishing android app

Tags: android

1. My android app, opens email editor, messaging app, and when user clicks on a button it opens a link in the default web browser. Also it opens Google Play store for rating my app. So are any **permissions** required to use these features?
2. I'm adding "share my app" button to my app which functions to open the messaging app with my Google Play link. But I haven't received any Google-Play link yet until I publish. So what to do?
3. Also I used low resolution images to reduce my apk size. But for tabs, can I publish a different APK with high resolution images? Or for different devices can different APKs be published? I couldn't find such option

Comment: These questions are better suited for google, not stackoverflow.

Comment: You don't need any play-specific permissions for sure. If it runs locally, it will run downloaded. StackOverflow doesn't support [b][/b], use *****Text*****. Google does not scan your app, you shouldn't pirate stuff anyways. You can publish device specific apks, but you shouldn't.

Comment: Any specific reasons, why we shoudn't?

Comment: Where's Google's forums? Sorry :(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about several problems at once. Some are better asked to a lawyer (copyrights for instance), others need their own question with more information (e.g. the one about permissions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No.
2. App links have the following format: `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your.package.name`
3. No, they are not scanning your app automatically but violations can (and will) be reported. Read about the policies [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113474?hl=en&ref_topic=2985711). Note that this is not Android-specific, you simply cannot use anything you find online anywhere.
4. Read the documentation about multi-device support [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/index.html), multi-APK pusblishing [here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/index.html) (the article also explains when you should/shouldn't do this).

*Next time please ask your questions separately, including more details about the problem and what you have tried the find a solution.*